# how to creat .mdf and .mdl files from live DB?

Tags: sql-server

I am very new to SQL and I want to update a table on a new site of mine with older live DB costing table. I have read that i need the .mdf and .ldf files from the live Db, but i have no idea how to create or get them? Please advice on this problem.

regards

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Different products do those things in different ways.)

Comment: If you already have a backup, you just have to restore the database. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-a-database-backup-using-ssms

Comment: What does it mean " I want to update a table on a new site"? Do you want the entire copy of database just to recreate one single table?

Comment: What is the size of your table? You can script it with the data as INSERT if it's smal, or you can use import/export wizard to copy it to another server

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server then what you need to know is how to [Backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql) and [Restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql) a database.

The following tutorials will explain how each is done.

[Backup Tutorial](https://www.mssqltips.com/tutorial.asp?id=1)

[Restore Tutorial](https://www.mssqltips.com/tutorial.asp?id=81)

Comment: Thank you alot, I am all setup.